# Permutation model in which infinite sets are Dedekind-infinite

Tags: set-theory, forcing

I've been looking for a permutation model in which $IDI$ (every infinite set is Dedekind-infinite) and $\neg AC$ holds. I have found several (for example in Countable Sums and Products of Metrizable Spaces in $ZF$ by Keremedis and Tachtsis, Theorem 14), but they all require a lot of group theory and very long proofs to show that $IDI$ holds. I was wondering if anyone is aware of an example of such a permutation model with a much simpler proof that $IDI$ holds?

Comment: I suspect this is one of those "looks easier than it is" results. It's trivial to make the set of atoms not have any infinite Dedekind-finite sets, but you then have to argue that no "higher rank" i.D.f. sets are created, and that seems tricky.

Comment: @NoahSchweber that’s the issue I’ve been having. Since most permutation models are created for more than the purpose of just proving that $IDI$ does not imply $AC$, I was hoping that it might be possible to create a pretty basic permutation model which is fairly unenlightening apart from the fact that in it $IDI$ and $\neg AC$ hold.

Comment: Any model of $DC$ will satisfy this. For example any example where the filter of subgroups is countably complete will work and there are tons of those.

Comment: @JonathanSchilhan do you have any good recommendations for a proof that the filter being countably complete implies $DC$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest examples are in Chapter 8 of Jech's "Axiom of Choice" book.

Simply put, it is not hard to verify that if the filter of groups is closed under countable intersections (or if the filter is generated by fixing an ideal of sets, then the ideal is closed under countable unions), then $\sf DC$ holds in the model.

So, for example, when the atoms have size $\aleph_1$, taking all the permutations of the atoms and fixing pointwise any countable set of atoms will do the trick.

Comment: Thanks, that's really helpful. Is it the case that $DC$ is equivalent to the filter being closed under countable intersections? In either case, would you be able to direct me towards a source that proves this/discusses this further?

Comment: While that is a very reasonable guess, it turns out to be false. Jonathan Schilhan and I found the correct condition which is slightly more involved and complicated. https://arxiv.org/abs/2212.10261

Comment: (When I started my M.Sc. and had to come up with some research questions, one of them was about this very thing. I was glad when last summer we got the condition down and found the answer.)

Comment: Thanks, that's super helpful, and it's very cool that you managed to prove it in the end. Any chance you know of an counterexample? (I.e. a permutation model that satisfies $DC$ but the filter is not closed under countable intersections).

Comment: Yes, we have an example in the paper.